# How to call a prototype from parent js

Tags: javascript

`Uncaught TypeError: this.rnd is not a function.`

What to do in this case? 
I understand that you need to use the call method somehow?

```js
var foo = function () {      
    var write = function () {
        document.write(this.rnd([1, 3, 5, 7]));      
    }
    write();
}
 
foo.prototype.rnd = function(array) {
    return array[Math.round(Math.random() * (array.length - 1))];
}

var f = new foo();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set it up this way you could define `write` on the instance so you can call it with `this.write()`. Each instance would have its own copy of the function, which is often unnecessary:

```js
var foo = function(){ 
    this.write = function() {
        console.log(this.rnd([1, 3, 5, 7]));
        
    }
    this.write();
}


foo.prototype.rnd = function(array){
    return array[Math.round(Math.random() * (array.length - 1))];
}

var f = new foo();
```

Alternatively, you could put `write()` on the prototype as well, then all instances would share the same function:

```js
var foo = function(){ 
    this.write();
}

foo.prototype.write = function() {
    console.log(this.rnd([1, 3, 5, 7]));     
}

foo.prototype.rnd = function(array){
    return array[Math.round(Math.random() * (array.length - 1))];
}

var f = new foo();
```

If you *wanted* to use `call()` you could do it like this which would manually bind `this` inside `write()` to the instance :

```js
var foo = function () {      
    var write = function () {
        console.log(this.rnd([1, 3, 5, 7]));      
    }
    write.call(this);
}
 
foo.prototype.rnd = function(array) {
    return array[Math.round(Math.random() * (array.length - 1))];
}

var f = new foo();
```

Comment: Thank you, all the answers are good, it is difficult to choose the best.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var foo = function(){
  
 var write = function(ctx) {
  document.write(ctx.rnd([1, 3, 5, 7]));
  
 }

write(this);
}


foo.prototype.rnd = function(array)
{

return array[Math.round(Math.random() * (array.length - 1))];

}


var f = new foo()
```

Comment: Thank you, all the answers are good, it is difficult to choose the best.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem there with the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope), of the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) . The code below would work

```
var foo = function(){   
    var currentThis = this
    var write = function() {
        document.write(currentThis.rnd([1, 3, 5, 7]));

    }
    write();
}


foo.prototype.rnd = function(array)
{

return array[Math.round(Math.random() * (array.length - 1))];

}


var f = new foo();
```

The problem here is that by the time you got to the write, the this was not the same this as the one for the foo constructor.
As you learn vanilla javascript you might find people doing also

```
var self = this
var that = this
```

Comment: Thank you, all the answers are good, it is difficult to choose the best.